# How use class interfaces when using PHPSpec

Tags: php, testing, laravel, bdd, phpspec

When testing with PHPSpec how can I use class interfaces injected into my methods rather then the actual concrete class?

For example I have a `Product` class that injects a `VariationInterface` into a method:

```
/**
 * ...
 */
public function addVarient(VarientInterface $varient)
{
    return $this->varients->add($varient);
}
```

Although since PHPSpec has no IOC container to bind `VarientInterface` to `Varient` I cant really test my classes.

Is it not best practice to code to an interface and not a concrete class?

Comment: You should code against an interface, not a concrete class. However, that's not you do in your example. As the "add" method doesn't exist on the interface, you're actually coding against an implementation. Also answered on the phpspec issue tracker: https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec/issues/584#issuecomment-67090359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock concrete classes and intefaces in PHPSpec.

Please verify this example:

```
<?php

//file spec/YourNameSpace/ProductSpec.php

namespace spec\YourNameSpace\Product;

use YourNameSpace\VarientInterface;
use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;

class ProductSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_is_varients_container(VarientInterface $varient)
    {
        $this->addVarient($varient);

        $this->getVarients()->shouldBe([$varient]);
    }
}
```

You just pass VarientInterface as parameter to test method.
This VarientInterface is mocked underneath by PhpSpec (really by Prophecy).

Please check offical phpspec documentaion about mocking http://www.phpspec.net/docs/introduction.html#prophet-objects